Как сделать, чтобы бот среагировал на любое сообщение, которое ему пришлют? Python Telebot
Мне нужно,чтобы при получении любого сообщения(фото, видео, стикер, текст, команда для бота и т.д.), бот сразу удалил своё сообщение, но пока этого не произошло, он должен изменять своё сообщение.
У меня не получается найти условие, чтобы бот реагировал на любое смс, которое ему отправят.
@bot.message_handler(commands=["test"])
def test(message):
    sms = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тест")
    if #здесь должно быть условие:
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, sms.id)
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=sms.id, text="Тест1")
        time.sleep(60)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=sms.id, text="Тест2")
        time.sleep(300)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=sms.id, text="Тест3")


Нужно просто написать
@bot.message_handler()

Без чего либо в скобках, тогда бот будет реагировать на абсолютно любое сообщение
